# using PayPal IPN with WhooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I have a web store which for it I defined an IPN in **paypal**.
lets say the address is:  `www.x.x` .
This is working great.

Recently I lunched another website with woocommerce web shop.
**The IPN that should be running hasn't changed.**

However for some reason, it doesn't work from the new site.

When I see the history of transcations in paypal...
I see that the Notification URL is diffrent that what is defined in Paypal.
Now it goes to:

```
https://My_Site/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Papal/
```

Why it doesn't go to `www.x.x` as it should? and how do I fix it?
Why does URL defined in Paypal are overwritten?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways of defining the IPN URL : one set in PayPal , second website will send it to PayPal via the code as a variable . If the IPN URL is sent via variable then it will override the URL mentioned in account .

So in your case the URL is being sent from WC to PayPal and hence over writing it .

Comment: How do I disable this in WC?

Comment: I m not sure of anyway disabling it on WC from the front end unless you comment out the code line which is sending the ipn URL .

Comment: I have access to the DB, if you can instruct how to do it... i'll do it. I think this is a BUG in paypal service. They should allow the paypal use have the final say in the matter.

Comment: Actually its not on DB but should be somewhere in the PHP file . Can you connect here https://tlk.io/eshan ,may be we can discuss in details

Comment: basicly all I want is that two different websites will go to the same IPN address.

Answer (score 0):

What you will look for is a variable "notify_url" (or NOTIFYURL if using our APIs) and the value of that variable will be the URL Paypal will use for IPN on the specific website.
As Eshan says, if the variable is present, it will override your Paypal account settings so you can remove that line with the variable and in that case, Paypal will then use the IPN URL defined in your Paypal account.
Hope that helps.

Regards,
Florian

Comment: can you please provide the code to do that? https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php   it's line 79 here but i don't know how to remove it or what will happen to the structure if it will be removed.